# How to skip entering security token in force.com deploy action

Tags: force.com, security-token

I have seen people just enter user name and password for the 'Deploy to Server' but it throws me error every time I skip the field.

Is there any setting in force.com where I can store the security token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set your IP address to trusted then you don't need to use the security token when accessing Salesforce via the APIs.

See:

- [Set Trusted IP Ranges for Your Organization](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_networkaccess.htm)
- [What is my IP address and how do I add it to the trusted network?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005349&language=en_US)